# An infinite set of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Let $x,y,p\in[0,1]$ and consider the following equation

$$px+(1-p)y = \frac{1}{2}$$

**Question**: I'm trying to find $x$ and $y$ such that the above is satisfied for all $p$.

---

**What I've tried**:

If $p=0$, then $y=1/2$, $x\in[0,1]$

If $p=1$, then $x=1/2$, $y\in[0,1]$

If $p=1/2$, then $x+y = 1$

If $p=1/3$, then $x+2y = 3/2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $p=0$, you see that $y=\frac12.$ And if $p=1$, you see that $x=\frac12.$ at that point, you know that **if** $x,y$ exist that satisfy the above equation for all $p$, then $x$ **must** be $\frac12$, and $y$ **must** be $\frac12$. All you need to do now is to show that indeed, if $x=y=\frac12$, then the equation is satisfied for all $p$. Should be easy to do.

Comment: So sorry I made a typo. The original equation should be equal to $1/2$.

Comment: @jonem I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Treat the LHS as a polynomial in $p$, then
$$(x-y)p+y=\frac12$$
Comparing coefficients (first constant term, then linear term, both in $p$, since the equation is true for *all* $p$) yields the only solution $x=y=\frac12$.

Comment: So sorry I made a typo. The original equation should be equal to $1/2$.

Comment: @jonem not too hard to fix, huh?